# Simple Injector: freeing up event subscription on injected instance

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

In our WPF project, we use Simple Injector to inject stores (implementing a common interface called  `IFluxStore<T>`) into ViewModels. The stores are registered as singletons, because they have an expensive initialization and data provided by the store to the consumers must be in sync.

The store raises an event whenever data changes, and consumers of the store will subscribe to that event. So, in code, that means:

```
public class SomethingStore : IFluxStore<SomethingData>
{
...
    public event EventHandler<IFluxAction> DataChanged;
...
}

public class SomethingViewModel
{
    public SomethingViewModel(IFluxStore<SomethingData> store)
    {
        _store = store;
        _store.DataChanged += _store_DataChanged;
    }
}
```

Works fine so far - however, the event handler is never detached from the store's event any more - the subscriptions to the event add up infinitely. Usually, I'd use a Dispose pattern or the like to remove the event subscription, but that isn't allowed for Transient lifestyle instances as those ViewModels.

How do I get rid of those subscriptions (and stray ViewModel instances)?

Comment: Have you tried making your ViewModels Scoped?

Comment: Yes, indeed. But the scope of the UI modules/components is shorter (i.e. as long as they are displayed) than the desired scope of the IFluxStore instances (live as long as the application runs). Would that work nonetheless? In that case, I'd need to create and destroy the scope at the same time the UI is created / destroyed?

Comment: The Lifestyle Mismatch constraint was loosened up in Simple Injector 5, allowing transients to be injected into Scoped components.

Comment: That's good news - I'll try that, thanks for the information.

Comment: To instantiante a new Scope, however, I need to inject the container into the starting point of my Unit of Work, so to say. Is that considered "best practice", as the UoW starts pretty far away from the composition root?

Comment: Yes, I would say that's bad practice. Try moving the UoW (or a derivative) inside the Composition Root while leaving the abstraction in an application layer.